EF Linq query on date
Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing:
DateTime mydate = DateTime.Now;
var myObject = db.Objects.First();
myObject.lastseen = mydate;
db.SaveChanges();

var myobjects = mydb.Objects.Where(a=>a.lastseen == mydate).ToList();

myobjects has no objects.  Even though I set the date.  I verify the date is set in the database.  Is there some kind of precision that I'm loosing?
Additional Information
The database field is a datetime type.  I did try changing the comparison from == to >= and the query did work, so I suspect that there's a precision issue coming into play.
The following code also returns false
DateTime maxdate = context.MacAddresses.Max(a => a.LastSeen);
Console.WriteLine(maxdate == currentDate);

I also tried changing currentDate to maxdate in my original code and it also does not equal.

Seems pretty much working code, you should check the EF config and make sure entity tracking is enabled, and if it is - check the query in database profiler or in debug mode.

You didn't tag the database you are working with, Is there some kind of precision that I'm loosing?, short answer yes. Why not compare the dates rather than exact datetime?

@ArthurEdgarov Entity tracking has no bearing on this issue.

What's the datatype of lastseen (in the database)? This question needs more details to be able to answer it.

And what if you mydb.Objects.Where(a=> a.lastseen >= mydate.AddSeconds(-1) && a.lastseen <= mydate.AddSeconds(1))  )ToList(); ?

Perhaps there is a time component as well?

After the revision: "so I suspect that there's a precision issue coming into play". Well, of course. 1/1/2024 00:00 isn't equal to 1/1/2024 09:12.34.567. I assume you know what to do now.

The resolution of the legacy datetime type in SQL Server is 3ms. Since 2005, when datetime2 was introduced, the guidance is to use datetime2 with the desired precision, eg datetime2(0) if you only want seconds, datetime2(3) for milliseconds etc up to 7 (100ns)

@flackoverstow suggestion  should be the recommended answer mydb.Objects.Where(a=> a.lastseen >= mydate.AddSeconds(-1) && a.lastseen <= mydate.AddSeconds(1))  )ToList();
